# Question on Serverless Microservices Project using AWS & NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, serverless-framework

I'm trying to learn Serverless microservices for an assignment. I have zero experience in AWS , Serverless and Microservices.

As I have understood up to now, I can create an aws-nodejs project using sereverless framework and deploy it to AWS and then I can have a Lambda function and an API endpoint. Then I have an microservice!

Let's say I want to build a complete system which provide free e-books and displays advertisements.

Then I will need an UI to communicate with the backend, I will need one microservice to get the e-books from the database, one microservice to load the advertisements. That means there are two microservices for my system.

Q1: Do I need to create two separate serverless projects for two microservices?

Q2: If I want to have CRUD operations in my e-books microservice, I will have to create 5 functions right? That means serverless framework will create 5 lambdas in AWS. Are these five lambdas considered as five microservices or 5 functions of one microservice?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No, with Serverless Framework, you can create as many Functions/Endpoints as you like within one project.

Q2: You can create 5 different Lambdas for your HTTP Verbs like PUT, POST, GET, etc. but you could also combine them into one Lambda.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html

But if you start developing with AWS, keep things simple and create 5 different functions. Later you will learn more about all those nifty other things.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to look through this free course available on the Serverless Framework website that can help answer a number of questions. There are some videos I need to update related to UI changes for the dashboard but other than that its a good introduction: https://www.serverless.com/learn/courses/full-stack-application-development-on-aws/